# How should I create Country Code Text Input Box in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]

How should I create Country Code Text Input Box in React Native?

Please tell me the code for the component and the style sheet too.
I already create the code for the text input box, but I just stuck how should I add the country code in the input text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best third-party library for this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-number-input

Or If you do not want to use these then use a dropdown picker you can do it. In this, you have to take all country code data yourself.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-dropdown

I recommend you use the first one.

Comment: flag of the country is faded in the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-number-input library, please tell me some another, if their it is.